# Failed to create folder while install matlab R2015a on ubuntu 14.04 LTC

Tags: software-installation, matlab

error message Failed to create folder (/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/).

and also when i creat these folders this msg appear 
Unable to create the destination folder /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/.  Please choose another destination folder.

Comment: Start the installation with `sudo -H install-script`

Answer (score 6):

I was getting the same error while installing.
the mistake was I was not giving `sudo` permission
you have to use `sudo ./install`
without `sudo` you will not be able to create the required folder.